# How to get the SMTP server response code in Django?

Tags: python, django, email, django-2.0, django-3.0

### Goal:

Hi! How can I get the SMTP response codes through Django, similar to return values given from the `smtplib` module??? I want to use Django's api instead of having to use that, and I see nothing in [Django's email docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/)

I know `send_mail()`, `send_mass_mail()` , and `EmailMessage.send_messages(...)` all have return values that show the number of successfully delivered messages... But I want the response codes for all of them. The point is to get proof that an email is sent, bad email address, etc, like [smtp response codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMTP_server_return_codes) show.

And it's looking to me like I'd have to make a custom email backend for this, and subclass from `BaseEmailBackend`... [It's using `smtplib` anyway.](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py)

### Example code for `smtplib`'s response code

```
import smtplib
obj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
response = obj.ehlo()
print(response)

# Obviously this doesn't send a message yet, but I want response[0]
(250, b'smtp.gmail.com at your service, [111.222.33.44]\nSIZE 31234577\n8BITMIME\nSTARTTLS\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\nPIPELINING\nCHUNKING\nSMTPUTF8')
```

Comment: why do you want response after ehlo()

Comment: I don't. It was just an example: *"The point is to get proof that an email is sent, bad email address, etc, like smtp response codes show."*

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check if mail is sent you can use return value of [`send_mail()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/#send-mail) function

> The return value will be the number of successfully delivered messages
>   (which can be 0 or 1 since it can only send one message).

Django does catch smtplib errors and returns 0 if any error occurred or returns exception if fail_silently is false ( default true)

from `django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend` source [`_send`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py#L116)():

> ```
> try:
>     self.connection.sendmail(from_email, recipients, message.as_bytes(linesep='\r\n'))
> except smtplib.SMTPException:
>     if not self.fail_silently:
>             if not self.fail_silently:
>             raise
>         return False
>     return True
> ```

same thing on [`open()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py#L41)